# How to Fetch the data inside PowerShell script which is calling from ADO webhook?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell

I am very new in PowerShell scripting,
So I am in a scenario like:

1. once a workitem got updated in ADO, servicehook automatically trigger a pipeline via REST api with the workitem data.

Now I have to receive that content coming from service hook in that powershell script. How I can do that?

[It it the serviceHook Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du9I7.png)
how can I able to access that data inside content in powershell script?

I tried to do some of the code found from google but it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, you are using the Rest API: [Runs - Run Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to trigger the pipeline.

In this case, it is equivalent to manually triggering the pipeline, so we cannot obtain the information in the webhook through the script.

To meet your requirement, you need to change to use Incoming webhook to trigger the Pipeline, then we can directly get the data in the webhook via pipeline parameters.

Refer to this doc to setup the Incoming webhook: [Generic webhook based triggers for YAML pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/pipelines/sprint-172-update#generic-webhook-based-triggers-for-yaml-pipelines)

Step1: Create the Webhook with the following API call:

```
https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview
```

Step2: Create the Incoming webhook service connection in **Project Settings -> Service connection**.

Step3: You can use the Incoming webhook in Pipeline to trigger the pipeline.

For example:

```
resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: webhook         
      connection: webhookserviceconnectionname

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-20.04

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    ### JSON payload data is available in the form of ${{ parameters.<WebhookAlias>.<JSONPath>}}
    script: |
      Write-Host ${{ parameters.webhook.resource.revision.id}}
```

In this case, you can use the parameters to get the webhook data.

For example:

[image]

Pipeline parameters format:

```
${{ parameters.webhook.resource.revision.id}}
${{ parameters.webhook.resource.revision.fields['System.AreaPath'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your guide, but can you tell me the flow? I read the entire doc but couldn't understand the flow

Comment: @KausikSharma when you complete the settings above, it will work with the following flow: **Work item update -> Trigger Web hook  to send the request -> Incoming webhook service connection will collect the request(including the data in payload) -> it will trigger the pipeline with webhook resources in YAML pipleine**. Then you will get all data in the payload request via parameters.